# Single word antonym of "premature"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

A friend of mine recently made a joke which was poorly timed; the visual irony had passed by the time she said it. I remarked that this joke was "postmature", then realized that isn't a word. Is there an antonym of *premature*, or can something never go past *mature*? For pregnancies, you can be *overdue* (thesaurus.com), but is there another such word that can also be extended to situations such as the one I had?

Note: I'm not looking for *mature*. I guess I'm asking this: can something pass maturity? Is there a word for that which can be used in a ubiquitous manner?

Comment: It arrived *late*.

Comment: It was "stale on arrival".

Comment: *Postmature* is a word; it's used for infants delivered more than two weeks past their due date.

Comment: 'Past its sell-by date' often (but not always) works.

Comment: But is there anything which can be ubiquitous?

Answer (score 1):

I think ***stale*** would be the word you're looking for concerning ubiquitous manner.
https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/stale

Answer (score -2):

Adjective: **precocious**  pri'kow-shus

Characterized by or characteristic of exceptionally early development or maturity (especially in mental aptitude)

"a precocious child"; "a precocious achievement"

-- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=precocious)

---

It is not limited to mental development, though that is the most common sense when applied to humans.

- Hares are *precocial*: Their young are born with fur, sighted, and somewhat independent.
- Rabbits are *altricial*: Their young are born naked, blind, and dependent. You might think of them as relatively premature, in the sense that they are not as well developed as hares.

Comment: I really wonder why the 2 downvotes, suddenly, after 3 years. Precocious really does mean the opposite of premature.